# Should I build a string first and then write to file?

Tags: c#, file-io

A program I am working on right now has to generate a file. Is it better for me to generate the file's contents as a string first and then write that string to the file, or should I just directly add the contents to the file?

Are there any advantages of one over the other?

The file will be about 0.5 - 1MB in size.

Comment: what do you mean by "generate the file's contents as a string"?

Comment: Basically, I have a huge dictionary which has to be translated to a file in a certain format with large parts of it hardcoded. So, I was wondering if I should write to a file as I go, or first write everything to a stringbuilder, and then write this stringbuilder to a file once I'm dome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you write to a file as-you-go, you'll have the benefit of not keeping everything in memory, if it's a big enough file and you constantly flush the stream.

However, you'll be more likely to run into problems with a partially-written file, since you're doing your IO over a period of time instead of in a single shot.

Personally, I'd build it up using a StringBuilder, and then write it all to disk in a single shot.

Comment: If a partially written file is a problem, one option is to write to a temp file and then, when the file is ready, move it to the intended location. That way you get both benefits; not storing too much in memory while at the same time ensuring that the resulting file is consistent.

Comment: Writing as a single shot **can** still give you a partially-written file, so it shouldn't be a reason not to write incrementally.

Comment: @Fredrik - true, I like that, although I'd use it in combination with a StringBuilder, due to error handling, which brings up @Rowland - also true, but 1) your chances are lower and 2) your error handling for that scenario can be in a single place.

Comment: I believe there is an element of fallacy in thinking there is a significant reduction of risk that a disk write will fail if you do it in a 'single' operation (partly because the single operation rarely is); Regarding error handling, you can still catch all those exceptions during your `Save(...)` method, right? so it is still a single location.

Comment: @Rowland, I disagree. The question said nothing about performing all the writes sequentially. If you have multiple calls to File.Write(...); File.Flush(); [do other stuff]; File.Write(...); File.Flush(), vs. one place where you write and flush the whole file, I personally believe you'll end up with code that'll be easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments. I ended up going the string builder route just because I piece together the contents of the file in a couple of different methods within the class and its easier to do so using one class data member.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a better idea, in general, to create a `StreamWriter` and just write to it.  Why keep things in memory when you don't have to?  And it's a whole lot easier.  For example:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("filename"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(header);
    // write all your data with Write and WriteLine,
    // taking advantage of composite formatting
}
```

If you want to build multiple lines with `StringBuilder` you have to write something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0:N0} blocks read", blocksRead));
// etc., etc.
// and finally write it to file
File.WriteAllText("filename", sb.ToString());
```

There are other options, of course.  You could build the lines into a `List<string>` and then use `File.WriteAllLines`.  Or you could write to a `StringStream` and then write that to the file.  But all of those approaches have you handling the data multiple times.  Just open the `StreamWriter` and write.

The primary reasons I think it's a better idea in general to go directly to output:

- You don't have to refactor your code when it turns out that your output data is too big to fit in memory.
- The planned destination is the file anyway, so why fool with formatting it in memory before writing to the file?
- The API for writing multiple lines to a text file is, in my opinion, cleaner than the API for adding lines to a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to use string or stringbuilder to store your data then you can write to file using File.Write functions.